# three.js intersectScene get empty object

Tags: webgl, three.js

I wrote two very similar functions for mouseMove and mouseDown. While the former works fine the latter keep getting empty object from var intersects = ray.intersectScene( scene ).

You can find complete code here
http://converteveryunit.com/pot/biluochun/temp/
Thanks.

```
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

    mouseX = event.clientX - homeWidth/2;
    mouseY = event.clientY - homeHeight/2;

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / homeWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / homeHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = ray.intersectScene( scene );
}


function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / homeWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / homeHeight ) * 2 + 1, 100 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = ray.intersectScene( scene );
    console.log( intersects);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with Three.js, but I can't help but wonder why your vector has a Z component of 0.5 in the first function and 100 in the second. If one works and the other doesn't, that certainly feels like a decent place to start.